# Given that $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ where $x>1$, find $f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: functions

Given that $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$  where $x>1$, find $f^{-1}(x)$.

I don't understand and how to start. Please help.

Comment: The function $f$ is not injective on its maximum domain. There are restrictions in which it is injective. To find them multiply $f(x)=x+\frac 1 x$ by $x$ and use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$.

Comment: Annoyance:  downvotes on questions that get mooted by edits.  If an edit moots a post, then point that out and the poster can delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Set $y = x + 1/x$ and solve for $x$.